# Springboot H2 Hibernate Error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, heroku, spring-boot, h2

I am using a Springboot application deployed on Heroku, but I am unable to use H2. I obtain several errors regarding to Url Datasource and Wrong Password and Username. I am trying to create automatically entity table.

**Main.java**

```
@Controller
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
  }

 }
```

**UserConfiguration.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserConfiguration")
public class UserConfiguration {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private float btcValue;
    private boolean sell;

    protected UserConfiguration() {}

    public UserConfiguration(Long id, float btcValue, boolean sell) {
        this.id = id;
        this.btcValue = btcValue;
        this.sell = sell;
    }
 ...
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=


###
#   Hibernate Settings
###
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**Heroku Local Web Execution Log**

> 11:50:48 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:48.872  INFO 12876 --- [
>   main] com.example.Main                         : The following
>   profiles are active: production 11:50:49 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:49.078  INFO 12876 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7e32c033:
>   startup date [Tue Sep 19 11:50:49 CEST 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy 11:50:50 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:50.612  INFO 12876 ---
>   [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     :
>   Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different
>   definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari;
>   factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred) 11:50:50 web.1   |  >  ; defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
>   with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false;
>   autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true;
>   primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat;
>   factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconf 11:50:50 web.1   |  > 
>   igure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]] 11:50:51 web.1   | 
>   2017-09-19 11:50:51.346  INFO 12876 --- [           main]
>   f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330
>   'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>   11:50:51 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:51.858  INFO 12876 --- [
>   main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
>   of type
>   [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$338a41d7]
>   is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 11:50:52 web.1   | 
>   2017-09-19 11:50:52.373  INFO 12876 --- [           main]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with
>   port(s): 5000 (http) 11:50:52 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:52.425  INFO
>   12876 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   :
>   Starting service Tomcat 11:50:52 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:52.427 
>   INFO 12876 --- [           main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine:
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.11 11:50:52 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:52.650  INFO
>   12876 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
>   Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 11:50:52 web.1   | 
>   2017-09-19 11:50:52.650  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 3575 ms 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:53.228  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet:
>   'dispatcherServlet' to [/] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:53.234
>   INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet:
>   'webServlet' to [/h2/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:53.256 
>   INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'metricsFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19 11:50:53.257 
>   INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:53.257  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:53.257  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:53.257  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'requestContextFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:53.258  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:53.271  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:53 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:53.273  INFO 12876 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'resourceUrlEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 11:50:54 web.1   |  2017-09-19
>   11:50:54.251 ERROR 12876 --- [           main]
>   o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial
>   connections of pool. 11:50:54 web.1   |  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
>   Wrong user name or password [28000-193] 11:50:54 web.1   |    at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:336)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:162)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:349) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:115)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:99)
>   ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar!/:na] 11:50:54
>   web.1   |     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |      at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |      at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |      at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:154)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |      at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |      at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |      at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na] 11:50:54 web.1   |      at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>   [spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE] 11:50:54 web.1   | 
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>   [spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE] 11:50:54 web.1   | 
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326)
>   [spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE] 11:50:54 web.1   | 
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
>   [spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE] 11:50:54 web.1   | 
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72)
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE] 11:50:54
>   web.1   |     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139)
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE] 11:50:54
>   web.1   |     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105)
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE] 11:50:54
>   web.1   |     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d10a5f7.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4()
>   [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]

As example my test using H2 dashboard, using empty password and user. Am I missing something conceptually?

***EDIT***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot db credentials, look at the stacktrace

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password
```

add to your application.properties

```
spring.datasource.username=(h2 user)
spring.datasource.password=(h2 password)
```

Default should be user: "sa" and pass: "" empty string if i'm not mistaken for h2

Comment: Can you see my edit? I also tried with "sa" and empty password.

Comment: ~/database imply a db stored in user directory...
either you are connecting to different db or i don't know...